# Как сложить элементы двух массивов или псевдомассивов между собой?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
"use strict";
let addExpenses = "2200, 1000, 9000",
question2 = prompt("Перечислите возможные расходы за рассчитываемый период 
через запятую");
console.log(addExpenses.split(", "));
console.log(typeof(addExpenses));
console.log(question2.split(", "));
console.log(typeof(question2));
Array.prototype.push.apply(addExpenses, question2);
console.log(addExpenses);
console.log(question2);
```

С помощью метода `.push` добавления новых переменных в массив `addExpenses.` из введенных данных(через `prompt`).

Консоль выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Comment: почему просто не сложить строки? `addExpenses + ', ' + question2`

Answer (score 1):

я не очень понял вопрос, но попытаюсь

```
let addExpenses = "2200, 1000, 9000";
const question2 = prompt("Перечислите возможные расходы за рассчитываемый период через запятую");
const SPLIT_EXP = ", ";

addExpenses = [...addExpenses.split(SPLIT_EXP), ...question2.split(SPLIT_EXP)];
```